# Mapnik: Parameterize queries for PostGIS datasource?

Tags: postgis, mapnik

My datasource is PostGIS, but I need to build the query on the fly based on user-supplied filters. Obviously I don't want to create an SQLI vulnerability, so I'd like to parameterize my query, e.g., "WHERE field1 = ? AND field2 = ?". I see no way to do that in the [documentation](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/PostGIS).

1. Is this possible with MapniK?
2. How do the rest of you handle user-supplied filters? Is there a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: I am attempting to show/hide certain layers based on the users interaction with a UI. Were you able to "on the fly" edit the XML file to turn layer statuses on and off?

Comment: Sadly, no. I don't believe this is possible with Mapnik.